# Get tweets for a specific user V1.1

Tags: twitter

I'm not really sure where to begin with this.

Prior to the upgrade to version 1.1 of the API I was able to request tweets in XML format using

```
$url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=' . $TWITTER_USERNAME;
```

A couple of things have changed, the return format is now JSON which isn't a problem but I'm not sure how to authenticate my app to request the tweets in JSON format.

I've read this [link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth) but am unsure how I'm supposed to implement it.

For instance, where do I get the consumer secret from ?

How do I request a bearer token in PHP ?

Any pointers would be great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use plugin that is written for v1.1, In new version they have added security layer so you need to be authorized in order to get the tweets via API, here are the links that will be helpful for you

http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/ http://www.fullondesign.co.uk/coding/2516-how-use-twitter-oauth-1-1-javascriptjquery.htm