# get latest tweet of a user without authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

I am creating a website using rails. there is no user authentication but all the team members data(name, summary of job experience, social media handles, etc) is saved in a json file which is parsed to show the data on page. I have a twitter handle of every user. I want to collect the latest tweet and the tweet's information(tweeted on, etc) for every handle. Also, if any of the user posts another tweet, that tweet should replace the old tweet. I dont have user authentication in my application. i did try on terminal

```
curl http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=user_name&count=1
```

but it gives me

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17094780/2463468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All requests to Twitter's API now need to be authenticated.  See the [documentation for the API call you want to make](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline).

You will need to register an app with Twitter and get your authentication tokens before you can start to make requests like that.

So, to be clear, the users do **not** need to be authenticated - but your *app* **does** need to be authenticated.